# Show that $\nabla(v\cdot A) - (v\cdot \nabla)A = v \times (\nabla \times A)$

Tags: vectors, physics

All of the variables are vectors. It is based on the lagrangian of a electromagnetic field, where v is the velocity and A the cross potential.

I've tried to prove it by using their modulus, sines and cosines but I don't think that's the way to prove it.

Could you give me any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about letting $v = v_1 \hat{i} + v_2 \hat{j} + v_3\hat{k}$ and $A = A_1 \hat{i} + A_2 \hat{j} + A_3 \hat{k}$?

Comment: This relation is incorect, notice that on the left side you have a differentiation of $v$, while on the right side you don't. It is only correct for constant $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the summation convention. Let ${\bf v}= v_i{\bf e}_i$, ${\bf A}=A_i{\bf e}_i$. We have, on the right side
$$ \nabla \times {\bf A} = {\bf e}_i\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jA_k$$
$$ {\bf v}\times (\nabla \times {\bf A}) = {\bf e}_i\epsilon_{ijk}v_j(\nabla \times {\bf A})_k={\bf e}_i\epsilon_{ijk}v_j\epsilon_{kmn}\partial_mA_n $$
Using the property $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kmn}=\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}$ we get
$$ {\bf v}\times (\nabla \times {\bf A}) = (\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}){\bf e}_iv_j\partial_mA_n = {\bf e}_i(v_j\partial_iA_j - v_j\partial_jA_i )$$
It is generally NOT equal the left side, which is 
$$ \nabla({\bf v}\cdot{\bf A}) - ({\bf v}\cdot\nabla){\bf A} = {\bf e}_i\partial_i (v_jA_j) - (v_j\partial_j)({\bf e}_iA_i) = {\bf e}_i \big(\partial_i (v_jA_j) - v_j\partial_jA_i\big)$$
As we can see, the equality occurs only when 
$$ v_j\partial_iA_j = \partial_i (v_jA_j)$$
that is when
$$ (\partial_i v_j)A_j = 0$$

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by $\epsilon$?

Comment: @galgarabel the Levi-Civita symbol